# JsonPath Parser Drupal 7 : grammar for context with filter in php

Tags: php, json, parsing, drupal-7, jsonpath

I'm using JsonPath parser in Drupal 7. My Json has this structure :

```
[  {
"Id": 1817,
"Type": 20,
"ImageUrl": "https://example.com/example"
  },  {
"Id": 1819,
"Type": 10,
"ImageUrl": "https://example.com/example"  },  {
"Id": 8091,
"Type": 30,
"ImageUrl": "https://example.com/example"   } ]
```

I need all items with Type = 20. For this, I'm searching for the good grammar. I've tried :

```
$.[?(@['Type']==20)]
```

but it doesn't import the items. Can you help me ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grammar seems to be correct. You can copy your Json and JsonPath in http://jsonpath.com/ and you'll see that the expression returns the expected results. That probably means that you error is not in the JsonPath expression, but in the code which is processing the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If there is an error, it comes from JsonPath Parser module... and I don't how I can resolve it... thanks anyway !